# Php Login not working with password_verify (Android)

Tags: php, password-encryption, password-hash

I'm having some troubles with my Login file due to the password_verify implementation. The file was working fine without the password_verify() validation.

Below my Login file:

```
<?php
      include 'config.inc.php';
 // Innitialize Variable
      $result='';
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $userpassword = $_POST['password'];

      // Query database for row exist or not
      $sql = 'SELECT password FROM user WHERE  email = :username';
      $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':userpassword', $userpassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute();

      // $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);
       $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if (password_verify($userpassword, $row['password'])) {
             $result="true";
                    } else {
                         $result="false";
                          }

      // send result back to android
      echo $result;

     ?>
```

Here is also my Register file (which is working well) for reference:

```
<?php

 include 'config.inc.php';

 // Check whether username or password is set from android  
 if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))
 {
      // Innitialize Variable
     $result='';
      $user = $_POST['user'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // Encryption of password
        $options = [
        'cost' => 12,
        ];
        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

      // Query database for row exist or not
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO user VALUES (NULL, :user, :email, :password, 0, 1, 1)';
      $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute();
     if($stmt->rowCount())
      {
         $result="true";    
      }  
      elseif(!$stmt->rowCount())
      {
            $result="false";
      }

      // send result back to android
      echo $result;
}

?>
```

Thanks for your support!

Oliver

Comment: it seems that `$row['password']` isn't hashed. Check manual [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Also when you have already bounded here`$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);` then what's the purpose of `verifying` again?

Comment: Shouldn't you get an error for binding `:userpassword` to the login SELECT without?

Comment: Thanks for your input. $row['password'] is hashed in the database. Hash is created in the register file.

Comment: Thanks Mario, took out the bind statement for the :userpassword but still not getting a positive feedback

Comment: If you are using `$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` then it's not possible that the index `$row['password']` exists. Either use `$row[0]['password']` or switch to `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Thanks a lot DarkBee!! I changed to $row[0]['password'] and that did the trick! Appreciate your help.